# Why no error on RequestNavigate to non-existent view

Tags: navigation, unity-container, prism

I have a small test app with one region.  I'd like to use the `RequestNavigate()` feature to change which view is shown in this region.

I can register my views, and can navigate to them OK.  For example:

```cs
Container.RegisterType<object, MyView>("MyView");
var regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();

// This navigation works ....
regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", "MyView", OnNavigated);
```

However, as user input is involved in choosing the view (and in the real app, views are registered in different modules with no knowledge of each other), I'd like to check that the navigation is successful.  But when I navigate to a view that I have *NOT* registered, the navigation succeeds and the user gets a screen with the string "System.Object" displayed and nothing else.

For example:

```cs
// This navigation also succeeds!?
regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", "MissingView", OnNavigated);
```

How can I tell if I've tried to navigate to a view that doesn't exist?
Why is `NavigationResult.Result` set to `true` in the `OnNavigated` callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it is implemented in Prism. The region first tries to get all navigation target candidate views via provided type name; and if it succeeds, it check some additional things (e.g. whether the views implement `INavigationAware` and if so - calls to `INavigationAware.IsNavigationTarget()`). If there are no views that could be found via provided type name, a new view will be created and added to the region:

```
protected virtual object CreateNewRegionItem(string candidateTargetContract)
{
    object newRegionItem;
    newRegionItem = this.serviceLocator.GetInstance<object>(candidateTargetContract);
    return newRegionItem;
}
```

Here is the method call `serviceLocator.GetInstance<object>()` important.
According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660853(v=pandp.20).aspx),

> If you call the Resolve method and specify a name as well as the registration type, and there is no mapping registered for that type and name, the container will attempt to create an instance of the type you resolved.

So this is why you see an empty view with a **System.Object** string: Prism just creates a view as a `System.Object` and adds it to the region; and then returns a navigation result object like this: `new NavigationResult(navigationContext, true)`.

So a possible solution would be to check whether a view of provided type has been registered in the container before navigating to the view.

Comment: If I check `Container.IsRegistered<object>("MissingView")` first that seems to work.  I can't help but feel that's the sort of check `RequestNavigate` ought to be doing for me, but that's what we've got. 

When does `RequestNavigate` return a `NavigationResult.Result` thats false?

Comment: This depends on the container you use. For example, using MEF container, trying to get a named export which has not been registered results in an `ActivationException` that Prism can catch. `NavigationResult.Result` is `false` in following cases: the region you provided does not exist; the view or its viewmodel implement `IConfirmNavigationRequest` and `continuationCallback` of the `ConfirmNavigationRequest()` returns `false`; an exception occurs while trying to navigate to the view.